# How to make a volunteering calculator in my html

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently coding a website in html and CSS. I have learned, php well at least enough for the thing i'm currenly trying to make. So I basically have the following,

How do you accomplish getting a number/constant 40 and subtracting that from a user inputted number. In a html document

```
 <form action="welcome.php" method="post"> 
    $string = "cool";
Hours:<input type ="text" name ="name"<br>

$string = "cool"
Hours: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit">
echo 40-"$cool";
</form>
```

this is wrong and will return the echo and original php code. If i wrap it in php it will display an error

Comment: I have no idea what you want to accomplish here. Firstly, you're injecting PHP inside HTML. Do you want to add another field where a user will enter a number, you would substract from your 40 and add on the word "cool", is that what this is about?

Comment: Lovely; the OP posts a question, gets answers and deletes the account.

Answer (score 2):

The $cool should not be quoted. Also, why are you setting the $string two times with same value?

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post"> 
<?php $string = "cool"; ?>
Hours:<input type ="text" name ="name"><br>

Hours: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit">
<?php echo 40-$cool; ?>
</form>
```

Also, the file itself has to be php, not html.

Comment: *"The $cool should not be quoted."* - Untrue. Had it been inside single quotes, I'd say OK. Variables do get parsed in double quotes, just not inside single quotes. However, how can the OP substract a number from a string; that's what I don't get. Here is a valid math equation `$cool = 50;

echo 40-"$cool";` will echo `-10` - `$cool = 30;

echo 40-"$cool";` will echo 10.

Comment: You're also injecting PHP inside HTML. OP needs an extra input for the user to enter a number, substract from it and concatenate the string "cool". Least, that's what I got out of the question.

Comment: Yes, it can, but actually **should not** (thats what I said, not can not) when you are using math operations. If he was using something like `echo "The bla bla is $cool";` then its ok. And I just used his own code. But ok, i will edit it. Also, the $cool is not set up in the code he sent us, so how do you know the $cool is string and not a number?

Comment: Ok, then dont forget to select the answer :)

Comment: The OP deleted their account; lovely. Oh well, what can you do.

Comment: Great :D At least you have that great feel of helping somebody :D

Comment: True. Well, the community now has a few *volunteering calculators* lol. *Cheers!* Let's just hope they don't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're injecting PHP inside HTML, you can't do that. It will produce a parse error, if your file is indeed a `.php` extension.

**Edit:** As noted in comments, you can inject PHP inside HTML, just as long as you include PHP tags and enclosed using `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>`; the latter being [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) syntax.

Now, as I understand it,  you want another field where a user will enter a number, then substract (from user input) your number 40 being a constant, and add on the word "cool" after the result.

Here's how and with the user's name echo'd also if filled and checking if it's a number using `is_numeric()`.

Sidenote: Using the number 2 in the input and with the name John, will output "38 cool John".

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number'])){
    $string = "cool";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $constant = 40;
    $total = $constant - $number;

     echo "$total $string $name";

    } // brace for if(isset($_POST['number'])...

    else{
    echo "It's not a number";
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))


?>

<form action="" method="post"> 

Name:<input type ="text" name ="name"<br>

Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

---

Footnotes:

You can also use an alternate method to echo the variables, such as:

- `echo "$total $string $name";` with a space between
- `echo "$total-$string-$name";` with a hyphen seperator

*as noted in comments*

The dot concatenation is just force of habit on my part.

*Sidenote:* You must use double quotes for this, since variables only get parsed inside double quotes.

Otherwise, you would get the following parse error using `echo $total $string $name;`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$string' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'...

Using `echo $total-$string-$name;` would work, but it will only echo the value from the substraction, instead of the intended echo'd string(s).

Comment: Why bother with `.` concatenation? Why not just use `echo "$total $string $name";` I also think that your first statement is unclear. You *can* put PHP inside HTML (if it is a .php file), but it has to be enclosed with `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>`.

Comment: @David Just habit. If the OP later wants to replace the spaces with hyphens, then all they'd need to do is replace the space with a hyphen. Good point though.

Comment: You can do that the same way ;) `echo "$total-$string-$name";`

Comment: @David Noticed your edited comment. Yes, you are right about that also, in regards to using PHP tags. I was pointing out the OP's mistakes. Another good point.

Comment: @David That would fall under a person's personal choice ;-) either ways are good. Thanks again for your comments ;-)

Comment: All things considered, it's a great answer. You may just want to touch up that first sentence to make sure that it's clear. +1

Comment: @David Duly noted and edited. Thanks again for your valuable input, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP for this at all. You can just use some basic java script. To use php, you need to set this whole page up differently.

Comment: No. Just no. Avoid JS whenever you can...